# why is a float not printing 1.0 and printing 1 instead?

Tags: c#

Why is my code not printing 1.0 and printing 1 instead?

```
            float version = 1.0F;
        Console.WriteLine(version);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Why would it choose `1.0` specifically and not, say, `1.00`?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Are you sure you did not get this backwards and it is printing `1` instead of `1.0`?

Comment: @Mody I take it that you read my comment as a advice to replace your `1.0F` with `1.00F` in your source code. It was not. I was merely wondering why you expect to see `1.0` in the console output, specifically, out of the many possible ways to print a `1`.

Comment: @GSerg Probably because that's what Java and Python (and probably a lot of other languages) output when writing a float to the console. C# is the odd duck in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  float version = 1.0F;
  Console.WriteLine("{0:N1}",version);
```

Check out the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Double_ToString_System_String_), about examples of the `N` format

When precision specifier controls the number of fractional digits in the result string, the result string reflects a number that is rounded to a representable result nearest to the infinitely precise result.

For more : Formatting of `8568.32179`:

```
//          N:                     8568.32
//          N0:                    8568
//          N1:                    8568.3
//          N2:                    8568.32
//          N3:                    8568.322
```

Comment: While this may be correct, you should consider adding details on _why_ this is correct.

Comment: @DavidL its working but he didn't add addition details why is this correct

Comment: @DavidL Sorry, Suddenly I answered, so I missed it.

Comment: @Mody hope u clear :)

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. It explains how to print the zeroes, but it does not explain why they don't print by themselves, which appears to be the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the compiler only printing significant digits by default.  In a `float`, `1.0 == 1 == 1.00 == 1.000` and so on until you run out of the float precision.  If the value was `1.5` or `1.05` or `1.005`, all of those values would print as they are significant to the value of the float.

In order to print a specific number of digits after the decimal point, you need to tell the compiler to do this with string formatting.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).